# Invalid project ID: (The caller does not have permission) in google assistant

Tags: actions-on-google

I have created a sample assistant app which I submitted for review, but it has been denied. I have changed the contents and tried to resubmit the app for review.

When I go to submit, I get an error:

```
invalid project ID: (The caller does not have permission)
```

And I am unable to submit it. Can anyone tell me how to create a new version of the draft.

Comment: How are you submitting it for review - via the console or via the `gactions` command? Can you update the question to include a screen shot of the error?

Comment: getting the same error.

Comment: @AkhileshDubey are you having multiple google id's logged in ur system